# Throwing an exception in a method with @Transactional in GraphQL

Tags: java, spring, graphql, transactions

I have a method with @Transactional annotation in which an exception is thrown. After which this exception is output to the stacktrace, then the exception UnexpectedRollbackException appears: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only, 30 seconds pass and "GraphQL execution canceled because timeout of 30000 millis was reached. The following query was being executed when this happened"

I tried to write various handlers, aspects, etc., nothing changed